# Laravel 5.4 - Stats by month

Tags: php, database, laravel

I would like to count all the users who have the state "visible" and "ghost" like this :

```
public function getStatsUser() {
        $data = self::whereIn('state', array('Visible', 'Ghost'))
            ->count();

        return $data;
    }
```

But i would like to have these data each month from the first user, like this :

```
['Month', 'Data'],
['December 2016', 4000],
['January 2017', 4600],
['February 2017', 11020],
['March 2017', 5400]
```

And for the date i have a row with "created_at" but not a specific row for the month.

I tried this, but it's not working

```
  $data= self::select(DB::raw('count(*) as monthly_total'), DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) as month'))
            ->whereIn('state', array('visible', 'Ghost'))
            ->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y'))
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->count();
```

The error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'month' inconnu dans group statement (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `oiseau` where `etat_actuel` in (Relaché, En convalescence) and year(`date_signalement`) = 2017 group by `month`)
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you keep a history of this state? It is not possible to do this when you only have the current state of the user.

Comment: Yeah i have, my whereIn is ok

Comment: In this line `DB::raw('MONTH(date_signalement) month')` you have missed `as` before month

Comment: I fixed that but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
self::selectRaw('CONCAT_WS(" ", MONTHNAME(created_at), YEAR(created_at)) as date, COUNT(*) as count')
    ->whereIn('state', array('visible', 'Ghost'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at)', MONTH(created_at)))
    ->get()
```

The query will return a Collection of objects with a date and a count.

Probably the most important part is to group by both the year and the month and you can use functions there instead of raw columns.

<sub>PS: This will get you Laravel Models from the `self` class, which they really aren't... so maybe replace the `self` with `DB::table('users')` or similar.</sub>

Comment: It's working, I have a collections per month/year with many weird stuff inside and among them there is an array with the date and the count.

Comment: But now i don't have any idea how to use it :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like:

```
$data = self::whereIn('state', array('Visible', 'Ghost'))
             ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as monthly_total') , DB::raw('MONTH(created_at) month'))
             ->groupBy('month ')
             ->get();
```

Or try Join Query if Month is stored in other Table.

Comment: Nice but i don't have a "month" row, it's only "created_at" so i tried something else with your answer but it's not working